# Add tags after posting a question

Tags: support, tags

Is there a way to add more tags to a question after it has been posted? I accidentally forgot a few as I was posting in a rush, and wanted to add some more but couldn't find out how.

Comment: link | **edit** | ...

Comment: +1 to your comment because it now points to the **edit** which @emish is asking about.

Answer (score 4):

Click edit.

[image: edit link]

And then add the tags.